# two different xml structure same output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, file-conversion

I would like to ask for help how to create correct xslt conversion if i have two little different structure of input format. I'm using xsl 2.0  for-each-group, but strugling with second structure.

First structure:

```
<DELIVERY>
<E1EDP07>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>CARTON</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_P1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>WP</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP09>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_A</MATNR>
    </E1EDP09>
</E1EDP07>

<E1EDP07>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>CARTON</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_P1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>WP</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP09>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_B</MATNR>
    </E1EDP09>
</E1EDP07>

<E1EDP07>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C2</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>CARTON</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_P2</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>WP</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP09>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_C</MATNR>
    </E1EDP09>
</E1EDP07>
</DELIVERY>
```

second structure is

```
<DELIVERY>
<E1EDP07>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>CARTON</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_P1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>WP</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>   
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>CARTON</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_P1</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>WP</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>   
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C2</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>CARTON</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>
    <E1EDP08>
        <EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_P2</EXIDV>
        <PCKAR>WP</PCKAR>
    </E1EDP08>

    <E1EDP09>
        <MATNR>PRODUCT_A</MATNR>
    </E1EDP09>
    <E1EDP09>
        <MATNR>PRODUCT_B</MATNR>
    </E1EDP09>
    <E1EDP09>
        <MATNR>PRODUCT_C</MATNR>
    </E1EDP09>
</E1EDP07>
</DELIVERY>
```

expecting output is:

```
<EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C1</EXIDV>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_A</MATNR>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_B</MATNR>

<EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C2</EXIDV>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_C</MATNR>
```

I'm using  xslt 2.0 with for-each-group. Which is working perfectly for first structure. But with second one
all MATNR are repeating which is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <DELIVERY>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="DELIVERY/E1EDP07/E1EDP08[PCKAR='CARTON']" group-by="EXIDV" >

            <EXIDV>
                <xsl:value-of select="EXIDV"/>
            </EXIDV>

            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <MATNR>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../E1EDP09/MATNR"/>
                </MATNR>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each-group>
            
    </DELIVERY>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

expecting result of both structure

```
<EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C1</EXIDV>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_A</MATNR>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_B</MATNR>

<EXIDV>SSCC_CODE_C2</EXIDV>
    <MATNR>PRODUCT_C</MATNR>
```

Comment: You expect one stylesheet to handle both?

Comment: Note that your first structure is missing a root element. And the output is not a well-formed XML either.

Comment: For the second sample, as the used XPath doesn't select the right values, can you explain in plain text why `SSCC_CODE_C1` is to be grouped with `PRODUCT_A` and `PRODUCT_B` while `SSCC_CODE_C2` is related/grouped with `PRODUCT_C`?

Comment: It is all rather confusing that you say you expect the same output as even the input codes are slightly different with e.g. `SSCC_CODE_C_1` vs `SSCC_CODE_C1`.

Comment: Sorry I just add root element and correct code to SSCC_CODE_C1  it was typo. In Second structure depend on position.  Like frist two occur of E1EDP08 belongs to first occur to E1EDP09 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the required logic for the 2nd structure (a very big if!), it could be implemented as follows:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/DELIVERY">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDP07/E1EDP08[PCKAR='CARTON']">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="EXIDV | ../E1EDP09[$i]/MATNR"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <DELIVERY>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$temp/E1EDP08" group-by="EXIDV" >
            <xsl:copy-of select="EXIDV"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/MATNR"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </DELIVERY>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, yes its actually almosts what I need. But need to include there as well 1st structure.

Comment: 1. I asked you whether you wanted a single stylesheet to handle both structures  and you did not reply. 2. It doesn't seem like the same logic can be applied to both, so you will need to identify the structure somehow and then branch accordingly. I am afraid I don't know how to make that distinction based on 2 arbitrary examples.

Comment: Little bit tune your idea and its working how I need now . Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/DELIVERY">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDP07">
            <xsl:for-each select="E1EDP08[PCKAR='CARTON']">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="EXIDV | ../E1EDP09[$i]/MATNR"/>
                    </xsl:copy>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <DELIVERY>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$temp/E1EDP08" group-by="EXIDV" >
            <xsl:copy-of select="EXIDV"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <MATNR>
                    <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/>
                </MATNR>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </DELIVERY>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>